# What one CANNOT do with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am about to give a short introduction to TikZ, and I was asked to add a slide of what *cannot* be achieved with TikZ.

So, are there certain types/categories of graphics where one should use something *other* then TikZ or using TikZ may be too complicated.

As far as I get it a partial list would be:

1. Involved 3D graphics
2. Plots that are based on large data sets (for example arrangements of curves in the plane)

What else should I add?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19669/are-there-examples-written-in-pstricks-and-they-cannot-be-done-using-tikz

Comment: @Martin: I saw this question, but I'm looking for a more general answer. Something like "if you try to plot X go look somewhere else"...

Comment: pgfplots can handle at least more basic 3D plots. Generally high number of datapoints are a problem because of the general memory limitations that exist (as you already know). I try to explain to people that they may not need 100,000 data points in a figure of 7cmx5cm because you can not see the the detail anyway. Escaping to gnuplot (e.g. from pgfplots) generally does a good job in calculating functions and such... I can't think of many other limitations, I am sure Herbert will :)

Comment: I think you can't convert text to pathes like you can do with pst-text.

Comment: @Jasper: platonic solids and polyhedra shouldn't be a problem, someone just has to sit down and put the math into a package/tikzlibrary. Fractals should be possible using shadings (or ”rasterizing” them).

Comment: For large data sets I suggest one should use a statistical package to do the plots anyway. My choice is R. And if one really need good looking plots, I will add the ggplot2 R package. And if in addition one want the fonts to match, I use tikzDevice, which output R graphics as `tikzpicture`

Comment: @Jasper (et al): I can do braids, knots, and links in TikZ.  Not sure what is so hard about 2-cells and 3-cells - maybe you should post a question!  I recently did a fractal for one answer (can't find it right now, it was the H-graph).

Comment: @Jasper: If you have any suggestions, let me know!  (The best place is in the chat room here called "From Answers to Packages".)

Comment: TiKZ does not, as far as I know, have the ability to define and use 'pens' in the sense that metapost does. Also, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212370/tikz-issues-mood-etc.

Comment: 1) TikZ cannot deal with fonts as Metafont/Metapost do. 2) TikZ, so far, only works with TeX, which can be something very good or terribly bad depending on your need (MetaPost is now a wrapper for mplib and external tools are independent of TeX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one wants to make **Interactive 3D** plots, he can use **Asymptote**.

---

That's an example. But the question isn't that simple. There isn't a sharp border between **it can do it** and **it can not do it**. Since there is an area called - **it does it, but the result it's not that good**. Or even **it does it, but the result is useless**.

Here are some considerable drawbacks of the example above:

- The resulting PDF requires powerful CPU,
- Works only in Adobe Reader (now probably in some other),
- It's almost useless for print.

Here is a [**video**](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/interactive-tex-aware-3d-vector-graphics/) as a reference.

So, what the conclusion is? Well, **Asymptote** does it, but the result is not that useful.
It can't be done with **TikZ**, but thats not a big deal, almost nothing is lost.
(Thats the overall picture, approximately.)

Lets look at the other side. So called **complementary example** - **the tool can do it, but the user can't**. Everybody can set every **PGF/TikZ** setting. But not everybody can make this settings typographically correct. Most of the users will prefer the defaults, which are far from ideal typography. And that's related not only to **PGF/TikZ**.

I wrote a letter to the author of pgfplots describing some obvious typographical incorrectnesses. (Can give examples, but I think thats unnecessary.) And he honestly answered something like - *I agree, but I'm a programmer, and thats what I can do.* 
You know, help from professional typographer is needed...

---

**To sum up the things:**

1. The app can lack a feature, but that feature may be of a little use.
2. The app can have a feature, but that feature may be beyond the average user's qualification.