# Tikz issues: mood etc

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm sorry if this has been answered before (e.g. see [Tikz drawing different type of arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141805/tikz-drawing-different-type-of-arrows)) but:

I am also new to the TikZ package, and I need to make this image:

[image]

in tikz.

Is there a quick way to typeset a halo without it making the diagram look prerenaissance?

Comment: *to make this image*??? I can not believe it is possible.

Comment: You'll _never_ be able to create the image above using TikZ (or any other vector graphics peogram for that matter); just include the image.

Comment: I believe this is just a bad joke, as the picture is part of the painting of Paradise in Palazzo Ducale in Venice, by Jacopo Tintoretto.

Comment: What?! I think tikz is a package for drawing, not a package for painting artistic images...

Comment: @egreg (+1) But I'm not sure I agree: there are certainly much worse jokes around.

Comment: "prerenaissance" – I love it!

Comment: @Holene The painting was realized between 1588 and 1592, certainly not what I'd call prerenaissance, but rather full renaissance or even prebaroque. Titian died 12 years and Michelangelo 24 years before Tintoretto started it.

Comment: Best Tikz question ever.

Comment: @Holene you can cancel out the factors to get the result as *nuisance*

Comment: @egreg Isn't that why the OP wants to avoid drawing halos which look prerenaissance? They wouldn't fit the rest of the diagram... [I certainly agree this is not a good joke. And, ethically, it is worse.]

Comment: Here's what you want: https://gist.github.com/cereda/8dff95134332a28ecf43