# Fading tikz path border

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

Quick and hopefully easy question. Is there a way to apply fading both to the filling and to the border of a tikz path?

**mwe**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (1, 0.5) {\Large\bfseries fading};
  \draw[ultra thick, fill=purple, path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**result**

[image]

I'd like the black border to fade to alpha in the same way of the filling.

**EDIT:**
Reading the comments it seems something specific to my setup, probably poppler/Evince, with chrome-integrated reader it works fine.

Here's the pdf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn402eaw7kil3cj/fade.pdf?dl=0

and the log file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhz9fclot9n0qpx/fade.log?dl=0

So, is there a way to make it work with all PDF readers? Not sure it matters, but I can draw something similar with inkscape (just setting border fill to gradient) and it works fine.

Comment: Mine is fading with the exact same code O_o https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdcjJ.png

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik weird, texlive 2017?

Comment: Ooops, no. Sorry, mine is 2015 yet. Forget what I said :P

Comment: Works for me with pdflatex from texlive 2017 https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXBNT.png. Also works with xelatex.

Comment: @samcarter this very same example? what could be going on? tried boh pdf- and xelatex, same result. Maybe it's evince, I'll try another pdf reader...

Comment: @filippo Yes, the very same. Can you add your .log file?

Comment: @filippo Can you maybe share your .pdf?

Comment: @samcarter see the edit please, it works with Chrome pdf reader, but I need it to work with any pdf reader and possibly look fine on print too

Comment: Any PDF reader is an impossible task. Adobe has the reference implementation. Sumatra on Windows is also pretty good. I see the faded border in your link by the way. So should you I guess

Comment: @filippo As a workaround you could stack the red rectangle without boarder on top of a black rectangle (a bit larger) with fading.

Comment: @percusse don't get me wrong, it's probably a bug and I'll report it to `poppler` devs. What I'm saying is that I'm looking for a solution that works around it that works with any pdf reader, if there isn't one I can easily enough live without fading ;-)

Comment: @filippo There cannot be solution that works with every pdf reader as there are also text based readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[black, path fading=east] (-0.07,-0.07) rectangle (2.07,1.07);
    \node at (1, 0.5) {\Large\bfseries fading};
  \fill[purple, path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, now I just need to find a way to make it work with more complex paths. Do you know if is there a way to scale a path with respect to its center? That way I could use just duplicate the path, scale it up, and fill it with black

Comment: @filippo Maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399382/36296 could help

Comment: thank you that's perfect (at least for paths with proper symmetry)