# pantograph file that says 'illegal copy'

Tags: graphics, watermark

I have a small publishing company that publishes, among other things, workbooks
for elementary school. These workbooks are frequently copied and nowadays they
are shared as pdf files on social media. In other words, the books hardly sell
anymore.
A few years ago, I received a Mercedes certificate of conformity via our car
mechanic whereby the word 'copy' appeared when copying.
After a long search I found out that it is a pantograph.

Can you make me a pantograph file (for black and white printing) 18 cm (landscape) that says 'illegal
copy'?
Can I then simply put that image on top of the layout in indesign, make pdf and
have it offset printed or digitally printed?
If there is a cost to create this image, I would love to hear from you.

I have no experience with TEX or something.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386723/

Comment: please don't close the question!
I really would like to have a pdf file with 'illegale kopie' (18 cm) because I don't know this programlanguage and I can't work with the software...

Comment: I don't think LaTeX is the optimal solution for this (and you) anyway. I did a quick search and there are also threads asking about this (using InDesign as well as other software) in other forums. Since you seem to be familiar with InDesign, I guess you could search more specifically about void pantographs in InDesign.

Comment: Could be helpful: https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/void-pantograph-creation/m-p/10651276