# Generating a fractal letter and/or alphabet?

Tags: typography, letters, alphabet, fractals

Is it possible in TeX or MetaFont etc. to generate a "character" that displays as a single letter at one scale but as a different character or even an entire alphabet at different scales?

So at standard scale, the character "A" would be indistinguishable from a normal solid regular A. But then when zoomed in the character "A" would look like a pointillist painting of a bunch of tiny As in the shape of a big A; or ABCDEG formatted in the shape of A; or even a bunch of tiny Bs? And from there, we might zoom in to a single tiny B such that it would be a look like a normal solid B (but could zoom in further for other letters).

- What would be the best way to arrange a tiny string of letters to
  imitate a single big letter, e.g. the shape of a Unicode character,
  so that it is a perfect visual replica of it (not just "kinda"
  like the outline of a character but virtually 1:1 in terms of shape, font-size, kerning, etc.)?
- For efficiency, would generating fractal letters like this be better 
  implemented in an entirely new language or would something like a 
  Python or LaTeX script suffice? Ideally, I'd want the
  fractal/recursive attribute coded into a single "character" such that
  any given letter or symbol will be able to be zoomed in and out of,
  but without requiring too many resources.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I am not saying that this is necessarily the way to go, but what you are describing here sounds a bit like a Lindenmayer system, see section 55.2 of the pgfmanual.

Comment: [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21548/121799) may also be of interest for you.

Comment: Wow, those are really, really helpful. For others interested in this question, the Lindenmayer named in section 55.2 has a freely available book that uses LaTex to model plant biology with fractals: [_The Algorithmic Beauty of Plants_](http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/abop/abop.pdf)