# Amoeba shape with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to draw generic amoeba-like shapes with TikZ and don't really want to think too deeply about its boundary. Basically a closed connected set with smooth locally convex boundaries.

Any ideas how to do this easily?

Comment: Perhaps this can help you get started: [Curve through a sequence of points with Metapost and TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54771/curve-through-a-sequence-of-points-with-metapost-and-tikz). It just a matter of picking the points to get the desired shape.  Try adapting it and if you run into difficulties post an update here.

Comment: Thanks Peter. It might take me a while, but I will try it and report back.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

More realistic amoeba with PSTricks.

### First Version

*Please skip this first version (as there is a small glitch) and jump to the final version*.

In this version I use `\psparametricplot`. After meticulously figuring out its behavior, I noticed that the last node is always included to create the closed curve. As a result, the first node and the last node are on the same radial line that make the curve has a visual defect on the curved line joining them.

I have no idea how to exclude the last node when using `\psparametricplot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset
{
    plotstyle=ccurve,
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=gray,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\psparametricplot[plotpoints=40]{0}{360}{/R rand 1001 mod 1000 div 1.5 add def R t PtoC}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Animation

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset
{
    plotstyle=ccurve,
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=gray,
}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=4+4}{20}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\psparametricplot[plotpoints=\i]{0}{360}{/R rand 1001 mod 1000 div 1.5 add def R t PtoC}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

### Final version

In this version I use `\curvepnodes` to produce a list of nodes. `\Pnodecount` represents the index of the last element.

Therefore,

```
\multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (P\i)}}
```

exludes the last node.

One advantage of using `\curvepnodes` is that we don't need to calculate the angle step.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\psset{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray}

\def\points{}
\pstVerb{666 srand}
\def\N{25}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\curvepnodes[plotpoints=\N]{0}{360}{rand 16 mod 15 div 1.5 add t PtoC}{P}
\multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (P\i)}}
\expandafter\psccurve\points
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Animation

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
\psset
{
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=gray,
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/6,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/6,
}

\pstVerb{666 srand}

\begin{document}
\multido{\io=15+5}{10}{%
\def\points{}%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\curvepnodes[plotpoints=\io]{0}{360}{rand 16 mod 15 div 1.5 add t PtoC}{P}
\multido{\ii=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (P\ii)}}
\begin{psclip}{\expandafter\psccurve\points}
    \rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{psclip}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 20):

Here's an example using one of the examples from the question that Peter Grill links to.  You need the code from the [TeX-SX Launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%2Bbranch/tex-sx/) site: download the file `hobby.dtx` and run `tex hobby.dtx` to generate the files.  Run `pdflatex hobby.dtx` to produce the documentation.  Once you've done that, the code is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green!50] (0,0) .. (1,0) .. (1,3) .. (0,3) .. (0,1.5) .. cycle;
\fill[green!50] (3,0) .. +(1,0) .. +(1,2) .. +(1,3) .. +(0,3) .. cycle;
\fill[green!50] (6,0) .. +(1,0) .. +(1,1) .. +(1,2) .. +(1,3) .. +(0,3) .. +(0,1.5) .. cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: amoeba shapes]

(although you should be aware that the specific syntax I've used above might break in future versions of TikZ; there's an alternative notation that definitely won't)

Comment: Much appreciated Andrew. :)

Comment: Note that the `.. cycle` syntax no longer works with `hobby`.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121310/86 for details and how to fix it.

Answer (score 13):

> I [...] don't really want to think too deeply about its boundary. Basically a closed connected set with smooth locally convex boundaries.

Whenever I have to draw curves when I don't want to *think too deeply about its boundary*, I just use randomized curves. For example, here is a solution using Metapost + Metafun (I am posting ConTeXt code, but it should work in standalone metapost as well)

**EDIT** As Karl's student's answer illustrates, you get more realistic looking amoeba shapes if you start randomizing with more points. Based on that idea, here is another solution: (I think that the amoeba with 20 points looks rather realistic).

[image]

```
\startMPdefinitions
  vardef amoeba (expr n) =
      (for i = 0 step 360/n until 360 - 360/n : (0.5*tand(i mod (30) + 20) randomized 0.1)*dir(i randomized 5) .. endfor cycle)
  enddef;
\stopMPdefinitions


\starttext

\startMPpage[offset=2mm]
  path a ; 

  for i = 1 upto 5 :
      a := amoeba(10*i) scaled 2cm shifted (i*3cm,0);

      fill a withcolor 0.8white;
      draw a withpen pencircle scaled 2bp;
  endfor

\stopMPpage


\stoptext
```

Breakdown of code:

- `n`: Number of points.
- `(0.5*tand(i mod (30) + 20) randomized 0.1)`: vary the distance of the point from the origin according to the angle `i`.
- `dir(i radnomized 5)`: `i` denotes the angle. Randomize the angle by 5 degrees.

### Previous answer

[image]

or with less randomness

[image]

These curves were obtained using

```
\startMPdefinitions
  vardef amoeba =
      (fullcircle randomized 0.8 cornered 0.15 randomized 0.1) 
  enddef;
\stopMPdefinitions

\starttext

\startMPpage[offset=2mm]
  path a ; 

  for i = 1 upto 5 :
      a := amoeba scaled 2cm shifted (i*3cm,0);

      fill a withcolor 0.8white;
      draw a withpen pencircle scaled 2bp;
  endfor

\stopMPpage

\stoptext
```

In the second diagram, I changed `randomized 0.8` to `randomized 0.3`. Breakdown of the code:

- `fullcircle`: draws a circle of diameter 1 centered around origin
- `randomized 0.8`: randomizes each "point" of the circle by 0.8. Since the circle has diameter 1, this changes the shape a lot. Lowering this number produces more circular looking shapes.
- `cornered 0.15`: Join the random points by a straight line, but instead of lines joining at right angles to one-another, join the lines by a corner of radius 0.15.
- `randomized 0.1`: Randomize all the points again, giving a scattered look. Leave this out if you want a smooth output.

Instead of starting with a circle, you can start with a more amoeba like shape to get more realistic output.