# Tikz: custom, rounded node shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to make a tikz drawing with two nodes as shown in my terrible drawing.  (The bottom node is meant to be round with some emanating projections that can be much thinner.  The top node is meant to follow the curve of the bottom node — a kind of thick arc, maybe?)

I also want to put some text in both nodes (in the top node, it would be nice for the text to follow the curve.)  But, the text is not necessary.

Is this possible in Tikz?

[image]

Comment: For reference, I found this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54985/amoeba-shape-with-tikz, but I was also wondering if it was possible without trying to install a library.

Comment: Do they have to be nodes?  How automatic would you want the method to be?  You could put the text in place and then draw the picture around it.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Yes, drawing around the text would be good as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not really a node, but works well enough:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\StrangeNode}[4][scale=1]% options, upper text, lower text, size
{ \begin{scope}[#1]
        \clip (0,0) circle (2);
        \draw (250:1) -- ++(270:3) (290:1) -- ++(270:3);
        \draw (210:1) -- ++(230:3) (250:1) -- ++(230:3);
        \draw (290:1) -- ++(310:3) (330:1) -- ++(310:3);
        \draw (210:1) arc (210:-30:1);
        \draw (30:1.7) arc (30:-150:0.2);
        \draw (40:1.7) arc (40:30:1.7);
        \draw[postaction={decoration={text along path,
          text = {|#4|#2}, text align=center,raise=0.3ex},decorate}] (150:1.3) arc (150:30:1.3);
        \draw (150:1.3) arc (330:150:0.2);
        \draw (150:1.7) arc (150:140:1.7);
        \draw (140:1.7) -- ++(130:3) (120:1.7) -- ++(130:3);
        \draw (120:1.7) arc (120:100:1.7);
        \draw (100:1.7) -- ++(90:3) (80:1.7) -- ++(90:3);
        \draw (80:1.7) arc (80:60:1.7);
        \draw (60:1.7) -- ++(50:3) (40:1.7) -- ++(50:3);
        \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0) circle (1);
            \node[align=center,font=#4,transform shape] at (0,0) {#3};
        \end{scope}

    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\StrangeNode{A strange game}{The\\ winning\\ move is not\\ to play}{\small}
\StrangeNode[shift={(5,0)},scale=1.5,rotate=45]{|\LARGE|ABC}{DDDD\\ EEEE}{\normalsize}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]