# How to draw curve inside a closed curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following diagram:

[image]

I have limited idea about TikZ but I want to draw this picture with TikZ. I have tried to draw the figure but ultimately faied. My written code given here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) ellipse  (49pt and 39pt);
\draw (0,1) to [out=90,in=190](0,-1);
\draw (0,1) to [out=180,in=195](0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Anyone can give an idea so that I can draw the picture?

Comment: It is not necessary to draw curve exactly I have drawn.It may be different. To show two paths from  $X_0$ to $X_1$.

Comment: Try to play with values: `\draw (0,1) to [out=-30, in=45](0,-1); \draw (0,1) to [out=-150,in=135](0,-1);`

Comment: But I can't able to draw arrow. How can I do that.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

After adjusting the `in` and `out` values a little bit and adding appropriate styles and nodes, one can get something like the following.

If the two paths inside the ellipse should have more kinks like in your picture you will need to give more coordinates and more `in` and `out` options (or [similar solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81604/16595)) or for nicer outputs the [`hobby` library](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) or the `smooth` options …

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    Arrow/.style={
        decoration={
            name=markings,
            mark=at position .5 with \arrow{#1}
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    Arrow/.default=>
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    auto,
    nodes={font=\scriptsize},
    every label/.append style={inner ysep=+1pt}
]
\draw (0,0) ellipse  (49pt and 39pt);
\path (60:49pt and 39pt) coordinate[label=above right:$x$];
\draw[Arrow]   (0,1) coordinate[label=above:$x_0$]
               to [out=-30,  in=45]  node {$f$} (0,-1)
               coordinate[label=below:$x_1$];
\draw[Arrow=<] (0,1) to [out=-150, in=135] node[swap] {$g$} (0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This shows 1 error : ' File 'standalone.cls' not found.\usetikzlibrary'

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar The `standalone` class is only used for this MWE. You can simply use `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}` as usual. (I’ve updated the code.)

Comment: It is working well.Thank you. +1 for you.