# Tikz curve without control points

Tags: tikz-pgf, plain-tex, asymptote

Is there a way in Tikz to draw a smooth curve that passes through some specified points without the need of specifying control points, like you can do in Asymptote?

For example, in Asymptote I can do

```
draw((0,0)..(100,0)..(100,100)..(0,100)..cycle);
```

to obtain a curve that looks like a circle.

What's the Tikz analogous for plain TeX?

Comment: Yes it's the `hobby` package.

Comment: @percusse In the package documentation I see that `hobby` is written using  LaTeX3.  I am running Tikz on top of plain TeX, so I can't use `hobby`

Comment: Then no there is none. Any reason to stick to plain?

Comment: @percusse I am not really using plain TeX, but OPmac, which is a set of macros built upon plain TeX.  The reason is that I like more OPmac than LaTeX

Comment: Ah then you need to ask @wipet

Comment: @percusse  But I don't think using OPmac instead of pure plain TeX is relevant for this question.  I mean, If a solution exists in plain TeX then it should work also in OPmac

Comment: You can (of course) use that Asymptote / hobby syntax with Metapost --- since that's where they got it from.  So if `luatex` is an option for you, you could try `luamplib` for drawing...

Comment: @Thruston I need to use `xetex`, so I can't use `luatex`.  But I can produce a picture with Metapost and then include it in my document.  This is not really ideal because I would like to use this curve construction inside of some already made Tikz picture.  Anyway, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes but there is none as far as I know for plain and thus for opmac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case perhaps `plot coordinates` with `smooth cycle,tension=1` is useful. I borrowed and modified daleif's code.

[image]

```
\input tikz.tex
\baselineskip=12pt
\hsize=6.3truein
\vsize=8.7truein
We are working on
\tikzpicture[x=0.5mm,y=0.5mm]
\draw [smooth cycle,tension=1] plot coordinates {(0,0)(100,0)(100,100)(0,100)};
\endtikzpicture.
\bye
```

Comment: I try it a bit and then let you know if this works as I want

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz

Comment: @User See mrc's comment above, perhaps of interest.

Comment: It seems to work right :)

Comment: Also: the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54771/484 contains an example showing the difference between `plot[smooth]` and the Hobby algorithm used in Metapost and Asymptote. Basically, `plot[smooth]` uses a simpler algorithm that gives less good results, although it's fine for a circle.

Answer (score 2):

Page 30 in the tikz/pgf manual?

```
\input tikz.tex
\baselineskip=12pt
\hsize=6.3truein
\vsize=8.7truein
We are working on
\tikzpicture[x=1mm,y=1mm]
\draw (0,0) to (100,0) to (100,100) to (0,100) to cycle;

\endtikzpicture.
\bye
```

the default unit in tikz is cm, so `(100,100)` was a little large.

Comment: Doesn't this produce a square instead of something that looks like a circle?

Comment: @User `\draw (0,0) to[out=90,in=180] (50,50) to[out=0,in=90] (100,0) to[out=270,in=0] (50,-50) to[out=180,in=270] cycle;`

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  This is not what I was looking for because you have to specify in and out directions, but it could be a good compromise :)

Comment: @User I do not ue asymptote, so I do know know its details