# How to fill a region bounded by a character and a graphic object with a color?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

There are 5 white regions bounded by the ellipse and character R as shown in the following figure.

> *I want to fill **EACH** of these regions with a **UNIQUE/DIFFERENT/DISTINGUISHABLE** color.*

How to do this in either PSTricks or Ti*k*Z?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](4,6)
        \begin{psclip}{\psellipse[linestyle=none](2,3)(2,3)}
            \rput(2,3){\psscalebox{21}{R}}
        \end{psclip}
        \psellipse(2,3)(2,3)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

1. Please don't suggest me to replace the character border with a new object by tracing it such as using `\pscurve`, `\psbezier`, or the like.
2. Please don't suggest me to use a tool provided by vector or raster graphics editors as shown in the following screenshot.

   [image]

Comment: Can you provide a TikZ version as well?

Comment: Do you want a solution for *this* specific R clipped by *this* ellipse? Or do you want a solution for any character from any font clipped by any closed curve?

Comment: @HiggsBoson: So, use Inkscape with Latin Modern font to produce this particular case and to fill each of these five regions.

Comment: Do you want different colors for each region? Or the same in all?

Comment: @HiggsBoson Please, change "a unique" with "the same", if this is what you want.

Comment: There are two different version of the *Paint* *Bucket* Tool. The classical version is a bitmap tool (like with Photoshop, Gimp, Paint, etc.). But there is also a *vector* version like with Inkscape (and may be Illusrator)...

Comment: Do you have an actual application where you need this, or is it a purely academic question?

Comment: @HiggsBoson: So you only have to do this once? In that case, wouldn't Altermundus solution be the most pragmatic (and therefore most time/money efficient)?

Comment: Look at [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58708/14500) about [Are there examples written in PSTricks and they cannot be done using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19669/14500) and mainly comment by Andrew Stacey...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

You need to use a grid

```
  \draw[help lines,step=.2] (-1.4,-2) grid (1.4,2);
```

To get

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}
     \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) ellipse[ x radius=1.2cm,y radius=2cm]  ;
     \clip (0,0) ellipse [x radius=1.2cm,y radius=2cm]  ;
     \fill[green] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=1.2cm,y radius=2cm]  ;      
     \fill[orange] (-1.4,-2) rectangle (-0.8,2);
     \fill[blue] (-1.4,1.5) -- (0.2,1.5) -- (1.2,0.8) -- (1.2,2) --(-1.2,2) -- cycle;
     \fill[yellow] (-0.75,1.5) -- (0.2,1.5) -- (0.8,1) -- (0.6,0.2) --(0.2,0) -- (-0.75,0) -- cycle; 
     \fill[magenta] (0.8,1) -- (0.6,0.2) --(0.2,0) -- (0.8,-0.8) -- (0.8,-1.4) -- (1.4,-1.4) -- (1.4,1) --cycle; 
     \node[scale=12,inner sep=0pt] {R};    
 \end{scope}
% \draw[help lines,step=.2] (-1.4,-2) grid (1.4,2);    
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

With the grid it's easy to define the five areas:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, sorry I didn't see your answer for one hour. I was too busy with painting apparently.

Comment: @HiggsBoson No I extract the points with the grid

Comment: @percusse I delete my answer during some minutes because I used only one color. I was busy like you with painting ! :)

Comment: I don't know but I'm not very optimistic

Comment: @HiggsBoson: may be with some tricks like [Outlining (filling) glyph outline with text in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21594/14500)

Comment: @HiggsBoson You get a problem because you forgot `[11pt]`You need to use `\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}`.