# Can I visualize the Bezier control points of a letter ... in TeX?

Tags: fonts, asymptote, technical-drawing

Without knowing anything about fonts, I innocently read an [article](http://learn.scannerlicker.net/2014/04/16/bezier-curves-and-type-design-a-tutorial/) on Postscript/Truetype Bezier curves.

The first picture in the article shows the letter *Q*, and it's Bezier control points. I'd like to look at more letters (also greek letters) and their Bezier construction.

I therefore installed the program [fontforge](http://fontforge.org/) and loaded a letter from the computer modern font (I belive) in `/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb`

[image: Omega]

This visualization is perhaps technically useful, but not very pleasing. So, I wonder, could it be done inside TeX? Maybe using TikZ `controls` function:
[image].

**Clarification for this option:** The letter can be drawn with TikZ as well, but I'm more interested in a nice visualization of the control points.

It surely isn't easy, as the font is stored in a binary format. Perhaps it can be converted?

**EDIT**

- @g.kov shows a nice visualization using *Asymptote*.
- I modified Andrew Stacy's script from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64087/can-we-extract-the-points-making-the-character-from-the-font-file?rq=1), and am quite happy with it. See below.

Comment: oops: related or duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64087/can-we-extract-the-points-making-the-character-from-the-font-file?rq=1

Comment: sorry for dig up this old topic, but I was wondering whether there is a way to export the glyph you have done with asymptote in TikZ so that I can change a few bits afterwards.

Comment: @Sebastian are you sure about the first link you give in the question? It does not seem to contain any letter "Q" in it, as you say in the second paragraph.

Comment: Indeed it seems the article does not contain 'Q' ... I may have been wrong on this or it was changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image]

Control points of a glyph path(s) can be extracted with `texpath()` function
in `Asymptote`:

```
// glyph.asy :
//
size(7cm);
import fontsize;

defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));

real wd=0.6bp;
pen dotPen=deepblue+wd;
pen dotFill=dotPen;

pen dotPenB=blue+wd;
pen dotPenC=red+wd;

pen linePen=deepblue+wd;
pen fillPen=lightgreen+opacity(0.1);

pen thinLinePen=black+wd/2;


guide[] g;

g=texpath("$\Omega$");

filldraw(g,fillPen,linePen);

pair a,b,c,d;
pair labdir;
int pointNo=0;

for(int i=0;i<g.length;++i){
  for(int j=0;j<size(g[i])-1;++j){
    a=point(g[i],j);
    d=point(g[i],j+1);
    if(straight(g[i],j)){
      draw(a--d,thinLinePen);    
    }else{
      b=postcontrol(g[i],j);
      c=precontrol(g[i],j+1);
      draw(a--b--c--d,thinLinePen);
      dot(b,dotPenB,UnFill);
      dot(c,dotPenC,UnFill);
    }
    dot(a,dotPen,Fill(dotFill));
    labdir=rotate(-90)*dir(g[i],j);
    label("$\scriptsize "+string(pointNo)+"$",a,labdir);
    ++pointNo;
  }
  dot(d,dotPen,Fill(dotFill));
  labdir=rotate(-90)*dir(g[i],size(g[i])-1);
  label("$\scriptsize "+string(pointNo)+"$",d,labdir);
}
```

To get glyph.pdf, run:

```
asy -f pdf glyph.asy
```

Answer (score 17):

After modifying [Andrew's script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64751/5019), I get:

[image]
[image: omega]
[image: percent sign]
[image: letter g]

How to do it:

1. fontforge script `font2svg.fontforge`

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/env fontforge
   Open($1)
   Generate($1:t:r + ".svg")
   ```
2. running (`chmod +x font2svg.fontforge`)

   ```
   ./font2svg.fontforge /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb
   ```

   Puts a file `cmr10.svg` into your folder.
    E.g. letter 'Omega':

   ```
   <glyph glyph-name="Omega" unicode="&#x2126;" horiz-adv-x="722"              
   d="M677 162l-33 -162h-159c-23 0 -26 0 -26 21c0 69 32 159 47 201c29 82 56 158 56 233c0 156 -106 228 -202 228c-91 0 -201 -68 -201 -228c0 -75 28 -154 49 -212c23 -64 54 -152 54 -222c0 -21 -3 -21 -25 -21h-160l-33 162h25c5 -25 10 -51 18 -74c5 -15 8 -23 66 -23
   h80c-13 56 -45 104 -89 170c-47 71 -88 140 -88 219c0 137 133 251 305 251c169 0 304 -112 304 -251c0 -79 -41 -148 -88 -219c-45 -66 -76 -114 -89 -170h80c58 0 61 8 66 24c9 24 13 47 18 73h25z" />
   ```

   Nice, these are the path specifications.
3. Running the [modified script](https://github.com/bashseb/texstuff/blob/master/svgtopgf_mine.pl)

   ```
   ./svgtopgf_mime.pl crm10.svg tmpstr
   ```

   My changes to Andrew's. It now writes (for each glyph), three files

   - `chars/gly_<prefix>N`, where `N` is the decimal unicode number. This file contains the glyph path (almost identical output of original script).
   - `chars/bezier_<prefix>N` containing the bezier control handles. TikZ 3.0 arrows.
   - `chars/pts_<prefix>N` containing all the points on the glyph outline (not used)
4. Then, drawing a new glyph is as easy as including them in a tex file:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage{tikz} % loads xcolor
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
   \begin{document}
   \definecolor{solbglight}{HTML}{FDF6E3}
   \definecolor{solblue}{HTML}{268BD2}
   \definecolor{solmagenta}{HTML}{D33682}
   \pagecolor{solbglight}

   %Omega
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=18]
   \input{chars/gly_tmpstr8486}
   \pgfusepath{fill}%
   \begin{scope}[thick,solblue]
     \input{chars/bezier_tmpstr8486}
   \end{scope}
   \end{tikzpicture}

   %Percent sign
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=15]
   \input{chars/gly_tmpstr37}
   \pgfusepath{fill}%
   \begin{scope}[thick,solblue]
     \input{chars/bezier_tmpstr37}
   \end{scope}
   \end{tikzpicture}

   %g
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=25]
   \input{chars/gly_tmpstr103}
   \pgfusepath{fill}%
   \begin{scope}[thick,solblue]
     \input{chars/bezier_tmpstr103}
   \end{scope}
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: BTW, you can use the SVG path data directly in PGF/TikZ; see the manual for SVG-Path Library.

Answer (score 11):

Metapost also lets you do this, using the `glyph` operator.

[image]

This was produced by the glyph visualization program from section 9 of [the MP manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/metapost), changed to show an Ω from "cmr10", and shown below.

The names of the fonts are those defined in the relevant map file (usually `pdftex.map`) and the names of the glyphs are the usual PostScript names (see Appendix E of the [PS Language Reference Manual](https://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf) for a list).

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
  picture q;
  path p;
  interim ahlength := 9bp;
  interim ahangle := 25;
  q := glyph "Omega" of "cmr10" scaled .2;
  for item within q:
    p := pathpart item;
    drawarrow p withcolor (.6,.9,.6) withpen pencircle scaled 1.5;
    for j=0 upto length p:
      pickup pencircle scaled .7;
      draw (point j of p -- precontrol  j of p) dashed evenly withcolor blue;
      draw (point j of p -- postcontrol j of p) dashed evenly withcolor blue;
      pickup pencircle scaled 3;
      draw precontrol j of p withcolor red;
      draw postcontrol j of p withcolor red;
      pickup pencircle scaled 2;
      draw point j of p withcolor black;
    endfor
  endfor
endfig;
end.
```

Comment: Why is there an arrow in the Glyph? (lower right serif)

Comment: @HenriMenke, there's an arrow because I drew it with `drawarrow` -   I did that just to show where the path starts and stops.  Because the path is cyclic the arrowhead points to the first and last point of the path; it might be useful to know this if you wanted to do something with a particular segment (I guess).