# Background clip to text Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, backgrounds

I'm using Tikz to design the cover of a book and I need to do something like this :[image: Bacgkround clips to text]

I've tried to use some tricks given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45744/how-to-put-color-gradient-to-desired-text-only) but it did nothing.

I'm actually using the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\begin{titlepage}%
\pagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%


% Logo
\node[opacity=1,inner sep=0pt] at ([yshift=-0.09\paperheight]current page.north){\includegraphics[width=0.35\paperwidth]{logo.eps}};

% Document title
\node (booktitle) at ([yshift=-.45\paperheight]current page.north) [above, text width=.8\paperwidth, font=\fontsize{40pt}{43pt}\selectfont, color=covertext, align=center] {\bfseries\@title};%


\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{titlepage}%
\setcounter{footnote}{0}%
}
\makeatother
```

Could you help me please.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem and shows the effort you have made. It will be much easier for us to help you when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can also check this related [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58851/9335) and [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63146/9335)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Solution without TikZ

Using text as clip path is supported by package `pdfrender` if pdfTeX (or LuaTeX) is running in PDF mode.

`\pdfsave` and `\pdfrestore` saves and restores the current graphics state, thus that the clipping ends after `\pdfrestore`. Since the graphics state include the current transfer matrix (e.g., the current point on the PDF page), the command pair must be used on the same TeX location. Otherwise the TeX coordinate system and the PDF coordinate system would go out of sync.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand*{\TextImage}[2]{%
  \sbox0{%
    \sffamily
    \bfseries
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
      \uppercase{\ignorespaces#1\ifhmode\unskip\fi}%
    \end{varwidth}%
  }%
  \mbox{%
    \pdfsave
    % Set clip path
    \pdfrender{TextRenderingMode=Clip}%
    \rlap{%
      \copy0 %
    }%
    % Now the image or whatever is provided in #2 is used.
    \rlap{%
      \def\width{\wd0 }%
      \def\depth{\dp0 }%
      \def\height{\ht0 }%
      \def\totalheight{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}%
      \raisebox{-\dp0}{#2}%
    }%
    \pdfrestore
    % Inform TeX about the text dimensions
    \phantom{\copy0}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \TextImage{%
    This text clips the\\
    background image%
  }{%
    \includegraphics[
      width=\width,
      height=\totalheight,
      viewport=0 0 {10mm} {5mm},
    ]{bg.pdf}%
  }
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The background image `bg.pdf` was generated with:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetseed{10000}
    \foreach \i in {1, ..., 500} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\colred{rnd}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\colgreen{rnd}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\colblue{rnd}
      \definecolor{col}{rgb}{\colred,\colgreen,\colblue}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\rad{.1mm + 10mm*rnd/sqrt(\i)}
      \fill[col] (rnd, rnd) circle[radius=\rad];
    }
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \useasboundingbox (0, 0) (1, 1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

This is a slightly tweaked solution based on [Mark Wibrow's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188065/4778).

It adds the `fit` library so that the front node (the one with the text) stretches to cover the background image without having to set the size manually.

This is the [image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p9ES.jpg) (place it in your Tex folder where the main document is, and rename it `vegetation`).

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,fadings}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  outline text/.style={
    execute at begin node={%
      \pgfsetfillopacity{0}%
      \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgflinewidth}%
      \pgfsetstrokecolor{#1}%
      \special{pdf:literal 1 Tr }%      
    },
  },
  knockout text fading/.code={%
    \tikz@addmode{%
      % Interrupt the picture to create a fading.
      \pgfinterruptpicture%
        \let\tikz@atbegin@node=\relax%
        \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=.]
          \node [node contents=, #1,text=transparent!100, fill=transparent!0];%
          \xdef\fadingboundingbox{{\noexpand\pgfpoint{\the\pgf@picminx}{\the\pgf@picminy}}%
            {\noexpand\pgfpoint{\the\pgf@picmaxx}{\the\pgf@picmaxy}}}%
          \expandafter\pgfpathrectanglecorners\fadingboundingbox%
          \pgfusepath{discard}%
         \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
       \endpgfinterruptpicture%
       % Make the fading happen.
       \def\tikz@path@fading{.}%
       \tikz@mode@fade@pathtrue%
       \tikz@fade@adjustfalse%
       \pgfpointscale{0.5}{\expandafter\pgfpointadd\fadingboundingbox}%
       \def\tikz@fade@transform{shift={(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y)}}%
    }%
    \tikzset{#1}% 
  }
} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]

    \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=.6]{vegetation}};
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{50}{40}\selectfont,text width=18cm, align=center,outline text=white, fit=(image.south west)(image.north east),       knockout text fading={
         fill=white, draw=white,
         node contents={THIS TEXT CLIPS THE BACKGROUND IMAGE}}];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

In TikZ you can use `tikzfadingfrompicture` from `fadings` library to clip using text.

In the following example I use a shaded rectangle in place of your image.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}

% the clipping text
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=title]
  \node [text=transparent!0, text width=0.7\paperwidth, align=center, font=\fontfamily{ptm}\bfseries\scshape, scale=3]
    {This text clips the\\ background immage};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

% use it to clip your image
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[scope fading=title,fit fading=false] (0,0) {
    % \includegraphics[width=0.7\paperwidth]{logo.eps}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \shade[left color=red, right color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (15,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: There are other related topics like [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63174/9335) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64473/9335).