# How to clip a gap between a word and its "shadow"

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I want to achive a text effect like this:

[image]

It is the "gap" between the word and the shadow.

I understand I have to use two layers to create shadow and word. But I don't know how to clip the shadow layer (adding a layer between word and shadow using white wouldn't help if using a background image.)

This is, how I would create the "word-layer" and the "shadow-layer":

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [inner sep=0pt, xshift=0.78cm, yshift=7.48cm, anchor=south] at (current page.center) {\fontspec{Arial Bold}\color{gray}Effect};
    %A "clipping layer" here
    \node [inner sep=0pt, xshift=0.8cm, yshift=7.5cm,  anchor=south] at (current page.center) {\fontspec{Arial Bold}\color{black}Effect};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Could anyone help with the clipping part?

Answer (score 4):

I would draw it three times since the shapes are nontrivial

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\y/\x in{0/gray,.4/white,0.5/blue}{\node[shift={(\y pt,\y pt)},text=\x] {Effect};}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very elegant solution if used on white background. I would like to the the background between the word and the shadow (if there is a backgroundimage).

Comment: Sorry, I meant "see the background" instead of "the the background"

Comment: @schmendrich That requires to unpaint the pixels painted by the shadow. and requires quite some effort

Comment: If even you (as a TikZ-Expert) say it's much effort ... :-( I thought there would be an relatively "easy" way, since I saw clipping examples like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249717/background-clip-to-text-tikz

Comment: @schmendrich Well expert no but the linked answer yes. However note that you have to punch through the shadow too to see the background through the white layer. That's the complicated part in my understanding. But you never know we have a lot of clever clever people here.