# cover part of a picture, defined by text

Tags: nodes, transparency, text

I would like to show a picture (in the example replaced by a red rectangle),
but only parts of this picture should be visible, defined by a text. So, in
this example only the part of the picture behind the 'TEST' will appear in
the final result. The text probably has to have opacity=0, but how to cover
the rest of picture?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (10,5);
 \node[font=\Huge] at (5,2.5) {TEST};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using the `fadings` library. Note that I use a lightgray background to show the size of the picture.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newsavebox\picturebox

\begin{document}
\savebox\picturebox{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{picture}}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fading text]
  \node[
      text=transparent!100,
      minimum width=\wd\picturebox+2\pgflinewidth,
      minimum height=\ht\picturebox+\dp\picturebox+2\pgflinewidth,
      font=\bfseries\fontsize{95}{95}\selectfont,
      fill=white
    ] {TEST};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %\clip(-5cm,-50pt)rectangle(5cm,50pt);
  \node(p){\usebox\picturebox};
  \fill[path fading=fading text,fit fading=false,
      lightgray!10% <- maybe you want to change the color to white
    ](p.south west) rectangle (p.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I uncomment `\clip(-5cm,-50pt)rectangle(5cm,50pt);` I get

[image]

Comment: Great! That's *exactly* what I need. Many thanks.

Comment: @Jürgen: You can also look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249732/2388

Comment: Yes, seems that I did not use the appropriate keywords when searching on tex.stackexchange, alas. Thanks for this hint.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \node[font=\Huge] (A) at (5,2.5) {TEST};

 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \clip(A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
 \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (10,5);
 \end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but no. You can get the idea by looking at this link: [link] (https://sylviamoessinger.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/bergfest.jpg)