# Upsilon with hook symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols, unicode

I'm looking for symbol which looks like this:

https://graphemica.com/%CF%92

[image]

I also found ϒ in UTF, but I'm not able to compile file and I don't find \Upupsilon satisfying. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you compile with an unicode aware engine, you can directly use the symbols (as long as your font has it)

Comment: Please include a picture of the symbol in your question. Questions on stackexchange should be self-sustained so they remain useful even if the link stops working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the easier is certainly to simply use lualatex (that provides UTF-8 support out of the box) and any font you like. To discover the font used in your case, I used firefox, selected the character, right click, inspect, and on the right panel you can see the name of the font that you use (you might need to click on the arrow to enable it):

[image]

Then, just do:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Tinos Regular}

\begin{document}
Hey α ϒ.
\end{document}
```

and compile with `lualatex yourfile.tex`:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I have to use pdflatex on overleaf. What do I have to  change in your code to make that work under these conditions?

Comment: Technically, you can use lualatex on overleaf as well (just change it in the options in Menu > Compiler). If you really want pdflatex… good question, maybe try to look into https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ if you can find a font that fits your needs, otherwise you can see if you can load the font using `pdfmapline` as explained in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F , but I don't know how easy it would be since it is an utf-8 symbol.

Comment: Otherwise, a dirty solution could be to manually extract the path and use tikz as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64751/116348 …

Answer (score 3):

Go to a terminal window and type

```bash
albatross -s -t U+03D2
```

then hit return. On my machine I get

```
        __ __           __
.---.-.|  |  |--.---.-.|  |_.----.-----.-----.-----.
|  _  ||  |  _  |  _  ||   _|   _|  _  |__ --|__ --|
|___._||__|_____|___._||____|__| |_____|_____|_____|

                     Unicode glyph with code points [03D2]                     
                          mapping to [ϒ] (AND search)                          
┌───────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Font name                     │ Available styles                            │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ .LastResort                   │ Regular                                     │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ .Lucida Grande UI Bold        │ Bold                                        │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ .Lucida Grande UI Regular     │ Regular                                     │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ AlgolRevived Medium           │ Medium                                      │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ AlgolRevived Medium Slanted   │ MediumSlanted, Medium Slanted               │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arev Sans Bold                │ Bold                                        │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arev Sans Bold Oblique        │ Bold Oblique                                │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arev Sans Oblique             │ Oblique                                     │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arev Sans Regular             │ Regular                                     │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arial                         │ Regular, Normal, obyčejné, Standard,        │
│                               │ Κανονικά, Normaali, Normál, Normale,        │
│                               │ Standaard, Normalny, Обычный, Normálne,     │
│                               │ Navadno, thường, Arrunta                    │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arial Bold Italic,Arial       │ Bold Italic, Negreta cursiva, tučné         │
│ Negreta cursiva,Arial tučné   │ kurzíva, fed kursiv, Fett Kursiv, Έντονα    │
│ kurzíva,Arial fed             │ Πλάγια, Negrita Cursiva, Lihavoitu          │
│ kursiv,Arial Fett             │ Kursivoi, Gras Italique, Félkövér dőlt,     │
│ Kursiv,Arial Έντονα           │ Grassetto Corsivo, Vet Cursief, Halvfet     │
│ Πλάγια,Arial Negrita          │ Kursiv, Pogrubiona kursywa, Negrito         │
│ Cursiva,Arial Lihavoitu       │ Itálico, Полужирный Курсив, Tučná kurzíva,  │
│ Kursivoi,Arial Gras           │ Fet Kursiv, Kalın İtalik, Krepko poševno,   │
│ Italique,Arial Félkövér       │ nghiêng đậm, Lodi etzana                    │
│ dőlt,Arial Grassetto          │                                             │
│ Corsivo,Arial Vet             │                                             │
│ Cursief,Arial Halvfet         │                                             │
│ Kursiv,Arial Pogrubiona       │                                             │
│ kursywa,Arial Negrito         │                                             │
│ Itálico,Arial Полужирный      │                                             │
│ Курсив,Arial Tučná            │                                             │
│ kurzíva,Arial Fet             │                                             │
│ Kursiv,Arial Kalın            │                                             │
│ İtalik,Arial Krepko           │                                             │
│ poševno,Arial nghiêng         │                                             │
│ đậm,Arial Lodi etzana         │                                             │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arial Bold,Arial              │ Bold, Negreta, tučné, fed, Fett, Έντονα,    │
│ Negreta,Arial tučné,Arial     │ Negrita, Lihavoitu, Gras, Félkövér,         │
│ fed,Arial Fett,Arial          │ Grassetto, Vet, Halvfet, Pogrubiony,        │
│ Έντονα,Arial Negrita,Arial    │ Negrito, Полужирный, Fet, Kalın, Krepko,    │
│ Lihavoitu,Arial Gras,Arial    │ đậm, Lodia                                  │
│ Félkövér,Arial                │                                             │
│ Grassetto,Arial Vet,Arial     │                                             │
│ Halvfet,Arial                 │                                             │
│ Pogrubiony,Arial              │                                             │
│ Negrito,Arial                 │                                             │
│ Полужирный,Arial Fet,Arial    │                                             │
│ Kalın,Arial Krepko,Arial      │                                             │
│ đậm,Arial Lodia               │                                             │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arial Italic,Arial            │ Italic, Cursiva, kurzíva, kursiv, Πλάγια,   │
│ Cursiva,Arial kurzíva,Arial   │ Kursivoitu, Italique, Dőlt, Corsivo,        │
│ kursiv,Arial Πλάγια,Arial     │ Cursief, Kursywa, Itálico, Курсив, İtalik,  │
│ Kursivoitu,Arial              │ Poševno, nghiêng, Etzana                    │
│ Italique,Arial Dőlt,Arial     │                                             │
│ Corsivo,Arial Cursief,Arial   │                                             │
│ Kursywa,Arial Itálico,Arial   │                                             │
│ Курсив,Arial İtalik,Arial     │                                             │
│ Poševno,Arial nghiêng,Arial   │                                             │
│ Etzana                        │                                             │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arial Unicode MS              │ Regular, Normal, obyčejné, Standard,        │
│                               │ Κανονικά, Normaali, Normál, Normale,        │
│                               │ Standaard, Normalny, Обычный, Normálne,     │
│                               │ Navadno, Arrunta                            │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arimo                         │ Regular                                     │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arimo Bold                    │ Bold                                        │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arimo Bold Italic             │ Bold Italic                                 │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arimo Italic                  │ Italic                                      │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Arimo Regular                 │ Regular                                     │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
```

The list is much longer, but it goes beyond the size allowed for answers.

Now you can choose the font you like most for use with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.